# Attempting to calculate how much change/money someone has given user input, returning as (dollar bills, quarters, etc.)

Tags: c, function

I am not quite sure how to fix the program to make it display the change someone has correctly. I will list the expected outputs and the actual outputs below, as well as the code that I have written thus far. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am very unsure about how to go about completing this project.

Expected output for input "4.67":

```
Dollar Bills: 4
Quarters: 2
Dime: 1
Nickel: 1
Pennies: 2
```

Actual output:

```
Dollar Bills: 223187040

Cents Leftover
Quarters: 0
Dimes: 0
Nickels: 0
Pennies: 0
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

double user_change(double);
void user_cents(int cents);

int main() {

    double user_amt, cents;

    printf("Hello User!\n\nHow much money would you like change for?\nEnter any           amount: $");
    scanf("%lf", &user_amt);

    user_change(user_amt);
    user_cents(cents);

    return 0;
}

double user_change (double user_amt)
{
    int updated_amt = (int) user_amt;
    int hundreds, fifties, tens, fives, dollar_bills;
    double cents = user_amt - updated_amt;

    hundreds = updated_amt / 100;
    updated_amt %= 100;

    fifties = updated_amt / 50;
    updated_amt %= 50;

    tens = updated_amt / 10;
    updated_amt %= 10;

    fives = updated_amt / 5;
    updated_amt %= 5;
    
    dollar_bills = updated_amt / 100;
    updated_amt %= 100;

    printf("\nDollar Bills: %d\n", dollar_bills);


}

void user_cents(int cents)
{
    int balance = cents * 10;
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    quarters = balance / 25;
    balance %= 25;

    dimes = balance / 10;
    balance %= 10;

    nickels = balance / 5;
    balance %= 5;

    pennies = balance / 1;
    balance %= 1;

    printf("\nCents Leftover\nQuarters: %d\nDimes: %d\nNickels: %d\nPennies:     %d\n", quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);

}
```

Comment: `user_cents(cents);` What do you think the value of `cents` is at that point? Considering the `cents` variable has neve been set. Suggest you do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements to trace the execution.

Comment: `dollar_bills = updated_amt / 100;` Again, do basic debugging. Look at what the value of `update_amt` is at that point. Is it what you expect it to be? Noting that the earlier `updated_amt %= 100;` restricts the value of `updated_amt` to be between 0 and 99.

Comment: @kaylum Will do, thank you for the feedback. I am pretty new and did not think to do this. I suppose I am wanting to take the value of cents from the residual inside the user_change function and plug that into my user_cents function.

Comment: You can return `cents` from the `user_change` function. In fact, you should be returning *something* as the function is defined with a `double` return type.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I am currently implementing a solution and I believe I have found my problem. Do you think it would be better to change this function to a void function, or in this case would I not be able to return a value for my cents function?

Comment: Tip: after `scanf("%lf", &user_amt);`, convert the money in the lowest unit, cents: `long 
 long cents = llround(user_amt * 100.0);` and then work the rest of the issue using integer math.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hey, thank you for the tip! For your cents definition, I believe I am missing what 'llround' means. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @neelish `llround()` is a function in the standard C library since 1999. "The ... `llround` function(s) round their argument to the nearest integer (`long long`) value, rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding direction."